# Oracle: create temporary table by a SELECT statement

Tags: oracle

I've tried to mix a CREATE TABLE table_name AS SELECT .... statement with a GLOBAL temporary table statement. They don't mix very well.

Is my example wrong?

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE a AS
(
   SELECT * from b
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

it should be:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE a
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
AS
select * from b;
```

(add where 1=0 too if you didn't want to initially populate it for the current session with all the data from b).

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but used Create Private Temporary Table, but got an error where TEMPORARY was highlighted with mgs: [Error] Execution (386: 16): ORA-00905: missing keyword. Can you please advise where I've gone wrong?